# ArcPy - Export to PDF - Script tool - What kind of parameter is a PDF output?

Tags: arcpy, pdf, python-script-tool

I am making a script to output an export to PDF. However, when parameterizing this function as GetParameterAsText () in the script in ArcCatalog, I don't know what type it is in "Data type".

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clear the default value and set filter to be pdf as shown below:

[image: Script tool]